# How to update state in specific rows in a table ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have icons in a table setup so that when an icon is clicked, a different icon is rendered. Now this works fine but I want to re-render a different icon for that **specific row** in the row that I clicked as opposed to re-rendering a different icon in every row. No idea as to how I would go about doing this. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            starIcon: true,
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({  data: data})
            })
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          starIcon: !prevState.starIcon
        }));
      }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Rank</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map((n) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                        <td> <span onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> {this.state.starIcon ? <StarBorder/> : <Star /> } </span> </td>
                        <td>{n.name}</td>
                        <td>{n.current_price}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: you would have to maintain index map of your rows that need to render stars for clicked rows. and then look for the state to have indexes changed that needs to render star icons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I see it, you need to either duplicate your starIcon boolean in an array that has the same length as your data array, or integrate your boolean in your data array. Here's a proposition for the second option :

```
import React from 'react';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({  data: data.map(x => ({...x, starIcon: true}) ) })
            })
    }

    handleClick = (i) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: prevState.data.map((x, key) => (key === i ? {...x, starIcon: !x. starIcon} : x) )
        }));
      }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Rank</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                        <td> <span onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}> {n.starIcon ? <StarBorder/> : <Star /> } </span> </td>
                        <td>{n.name}</td>
                        <td>{n.current_price}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Works great thanks... Just to let you know that you are missing a bracket in two places... on the setState method in componentDidMount and the handleClick method.